# Bind Inner Grid in Nested RadGrid from CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Hi I'm fooling around with the nesting feature on the radgrid.  How can I reference and bind a rad grid nested within a parent Radgrid in the OnItemDataBound Event.

I have tried

```
   var doc_grid = (RadGrid) item["doc_grid"].Controls[0];
   var doc_grid = (RadGrid)RadGrid1.FindControl("doc_grid");
```

Do I have to ref the NestView ...

Here is the general gist of the code ...

```
   <telerik:RadGrid ID="outerGrid" DataSourceID="SQL_Outer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" OnItemDataBound="RowBound" DataKeyNames="MatNo"
        ShowGroupPanel="True">
        <MasterTableView DataSourceID="SQL_Outer" AllowMultiColumnSorting="True" DataKeyNames="MatNo" GroupLoadMode="Server">
            <Columns>
               <%--Stuff--%>
            </Columns>
            <NestedViewSettings DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <ParentTableRelation>
                    <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="sysid" MasterKeyField="MatNo" />
                </ParentTableRelation>
            </NestedViewSettings>
            <NestedViewTemplate>

            <asp:Panel ID="NestedViewPanel" runat="server" CssClass="viewWrap">
               <div class="contactWrap">
                <telerik:RadGrid ID="doc_grid" runat="server">
                    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="sysid">
                      <%--Stuff--%>
                    </MasterTableView>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>

            </NestedViewTemplate>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void RowBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        var item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        var mat_no = item.GetDataKeyValue("MatNo");

        //!!!!I Can't figure out how to Reference the Inner RadGrid!!!!
        //var doc_grid = (RadGrid) item["doc_grid"].Controls[0];
        var doc_grid = (RadGrid)RadGrid1.FindControl("doc_grid");

        using (var con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimeMatters11ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT sysid, ccode, [desc], [View] = '<a href=\"'+ filename + '\">View Doc</a>' " +
                                     "FROM lntmu11.document " +
                                     "WHERE mat_no = @matno", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matno", mat_no); 
            con.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            doc_grid.DataSource = reader;
            doc_grid.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast as GridNestedViewItem instead of GridDataItem.

```
protected void RowBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item is GridNestedViewItem)
   {
      GridNestedViewItem item = e.Item as GridNestedViewItem;
   }
}
```